# ffmpeg : Is this a bug in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging, ffmpeg

I debug the ffmpeg program on the macosx with xcode.I find a bug with xcode(or lldb)。

```
code @ ffmpeg_opt.c-->static int open_input_file(OptionsContext *o, const char *filename)
```

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    av_log(NULL,AV_LOG_INFO,"func:%s(%d) filename:%s \n", __func__,__LINE__,filename);
#endif

    if (!strcmp(filename, "-"))  //after step over,the debug windows show filename=NULL.
        filename = "pipe:";

#ifdef DEBUG
    av_log(NULL,AV_LOG_INFO,"func:%s(%d) filename:%s \n", __func__,__LINE__,filename); 
    //but it can print the correct value。
#endif
```

you can clone the project from https://github.com/daozhao/FFmpeg.git, and checkout branch(release/2.2withComment) which is include xcode project file. you can debug with `FFmpegMakefile targets` try it.

you can see the screen record on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rTLirTGPM4 .

my OS:10.9.2, xcode:5.1.1

Comment: And what is the bug? What do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project use External Build System to build.
the `Makefile` is automatically generated by ffmpeg configure.
and  It adds compiler optimization option `-O3`. 
Therefore, the appearance of the upper case.
That's no problem when remote the compiler option `-O3`.